# Python OpenCV2 Code Displays Image in Windows and OSX, but not Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to write a GUI using tkinter to display an image and perform various transformations on it. The following code snippet works fine in my GUI for displaying an image in a separate window when run in Windows and OSX (I used Eclipse with pydev to write it):

```
img = cv.imread(file)   
cv.imshow("Original", img)
cv.moveWindow("Original", 400, 0)
```

But in Ubuntu, when I run this code, the gui comes up fine, but no image appears. I added

```
cv.waitKey(0)
```

and the image displays, but when I hit a key, not only does the image disappear, my whole app closes.

I am puzzled as to why the app does what I want (close image while keeping GUI alive to select and transform another) only in Windows and OSX, but not when using Ubuntu 12.04. Is there a relatively easy way to get the app to do what I want when I run it in Ubuntu?